# Drawing an L shape button with hover effect purely with CSS3

Tags: html, css, button, polygon

Been trying to figure out how to create an L shape button using only CSS3. I've managed to do it by mirroring a rectangle to create the shape but I am also trying to implement a hover effect on the button as well. It works only on the main rectangular shape.

Any ideas on how to go around this or possibly a more efficient way of executing this problem.

here's the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kryon17/kpRKA/

Comment: I thought of doing that as well but I want to know if creating this shape would be possible seeing that I have seen CSS stars around.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is what you needed, but I recreated it using borders.  Let me know if this solves your problem.

#### HTML

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="rectangle rectangle1" target="_blank"></a>​
```

#### CSS

```
a {
    margin:100px;
    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border-bottom: 30px solid black;
    border-right: 30px solid black;

}

a:hover {
    border-color: #676767;
   -webkit-transition: all  0.25s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-out;
}
```

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/mnht2/) | [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mnht2/show)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I was trying to do. Appreciate the help.=)

Comment: I got a follow up question how do you arrange them so that each button would be on the corner of a square div place in the middle of the page?  Here's a link to an image im trying to do.

Comment: The purple boxes would be the L shape button. Thanks

Comment: @JBON hm... I'd love to help you with this once I get off work.  Probably the best way would be to have a container div with the css attribute `position:relative;` and then have each button be `position:absolute;`.  You would then apply `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` attributes to them.  e.g. the top left one would be `position:absolute; left:0px; top:0px;`.  I'll throw together an example after I get home.

Comment: Got bored at work... http://jsbin.com/esayip/1/edit.  It'll need tweaking, but this should work. [demo](http://jsbin.com/esayip/1)

Comment: I'm always trying to do things the hard way. Thank you again.=)

Comment: @JBON You're welcome.  If you have any other questions, don't hesitate to ask.